# How to get String Index in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I am working on an app that needs to read a string of numbers.

I have a series of labels that are going to read the numbers and I need them to display it.

However, I cannot figure out how to read the index of a string in SwiftUI

I have seen this done in swift by doing

```
let input = "Blah"
let char = input[3]

extension StringProtocol {
    subscript(offset: Int) -> Character {
        self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: offset)]
    }
}
```

what I am trying to achieve is this.

```
@State var id = "12345"
@State var label1 = id[0]
@State var label2 = id[1]
etc
```

I know a string is not an array, but im trying to basically get it that way.
The ID comes from a text input.

Comment: It seems unlikely that `label1` and `label2` should be `@State` variables -- they should probably be computed properties.

Comment: you are correct, but I was hardcoding some state variables to test out what im doing.

Comment: In that case you should be able to use your `extension StringProtocol` `subscript` within the computed property. Did you try that?

Comment: I did, i could not get it to work.

Comment: Can you show your attempt in a [mre]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your approach to getting the character at an offset is smart and works well. Here is an example use:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

extension StringProtocol {
    subscript(offset: Int) -> Character {
        self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: offset)]
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var id: String = "12345"
    @State var label1: Character = Character(" ")
    @State var label2: Character = Character(" ")
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("id: " + id)
            Text("label1: " + String(label1))
            Text("label2: " + String(label2))
        }
        .onAppear {
            label1 = id[0]
            label2 = id[1]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. This works as long as the string is provided. What if i want to read the string from a text input. When the string is empty it throws an error on the extension.

Comment: Ill ask it in a new question. Since this answered what I needed. THank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `id` like that since it hasn't been set yet.

Instead, use your own initializer:

```
@State var id: String
@State var label1: Character
@State var label2: Character

/* ... */

init(id: String) {
    self.id = id
    label1 = id[0]
    label2 = id[1]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but doing this does not allow me to display it in a label.

Comment: @Bnd10706 I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: When I tried this in Label(label1, systemImage: "")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .frame(height: 48)

Comment: @Bnd10706 Because it is returning `Character`, as your subscript stated. To convert it to a `String`, do `Label(String(label1), systemImage: "")...`

Comment: 'subscript(_:)' is unavailable: cannot subscript String with an Int, use a String.Index instead.

Comment: @Bnd10706 I'm not sure why that's unavailable, is the code in the same module?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240482/discussion-between-bnd10706-and-george).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way for you:

```
func characterOf(_ string: String, offset: Int) -> Character? {

    let array = Array(string)
    
    if Array(string).indices.contains(offset) {
        return array[offset]
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }

}
```

use case:

```
print(characterOf("Hello, world!", offset: 7) ?? "Error with offset!")  // Result: Optional("w")
```